# Do I need to control trace impedance for DDR2 memory?

Tags: pcb, impedance, ddr2

I am going to try to interface low-speed 8bit DDR2 chip to FPGA, and I've got some questions crucial to make it work :-)

3) What is up with controlled impedance of PCB traces? Why it's important? What will happen if I would just have usual non-controlled 0.15mm traces? (distance between FPGA & DDR2 chips is 5cm).

Aligning trace length (especially on data & clock lines) is pretty clear, shouldn't be a problem as distances & frequency is low. As far as I understand there is still some 5-20cm length difference tolerance on DQ, but no harm making it equal.

Comment: what are the required rise and fall times for the signal?  And does it just go from 1 pin on the FPGA to 1 pin on the memory or will each signal make multiple stops?

Comment: 1 to 1, no other devices or multi-chip memory configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned that it will be low-speed then you most likely should not bother about impedance. The question is what exactly speed you are planning to go for?

My experience shows that you should think about impedance if the memory speed over 200MHz. If it's less than this number, there shouldn't be any problem, unless you have unusual PCB setup (6 layers, for example). But if you have, let's say, 4 layer PCB with two dedicated power planes, traces up to 3 inches can be even left without any termination at all. Just align the traces and you're done.

Anyway, if something went wrong, you always have the possibility to talk with memory on lower speeds.

Comment: Unfortunately, DDR2 have a lower speed limit 150-200Mhz, that means 300-400Mhz data transmission. The crazy thing is that I want to use just 2 layers.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs, I always try to remember, it is the rising edge that will kill you, not the clock frequency. Often as you increase one you are increasing the other also, but with a high rising edge speed you could easily false trigger something that you were only planning to use at 10MHz.

Comment: @barsmonster make sure you have a very good ground plane under all of that! In applications like this it is very bad to have a trace cut across your plane. This is usually a big reason why people go to 4+ layers (because they just cant get a good plane otherwise)

Comment: @Kellenjb: Yes, plus small addition: for high speed pcb's, if you have the ground plane, you should also have the power plane too, which will compensate and lower down EMI.

Comment: @BarsMonster: IMO, it will be really tricky to accomplish this on 2 layer PCB. Perhaps it's worth to move to 4 layer PCB? I mean.. headache vs pcb price? :)

Comment: @Andrejs ,it's about doing something with my hands :-) And doing 4-layer board manually is tricky a little. Without that I would just buy finished product :-) Anyway, I can still do some kind of ground planes by glueing grounded foil on top of these DDR2 traces.

Comment: @BarsMonster, you are just going to need a large board and try to avoid embedded traces in your ground plane.

Comment: @Kortuk, sorry I don't understand what you said here :-) COuld you please give a bit more explanations for the stupid?

Comment: @BarsMonster, you are not stupid, these are terms you must be taught. An embedded trace is a point where you do not have a continuous ground plane so that you can route one of your other traces. A perfect ground place is just a solid sheet. There will be small gaps where vias are used, but excluding that, your target should be a solid ground plane.

Comment: @BarsMonster: After you will get it to work, I would like to hear the results :)

Comment: I have successfully run DDR2 chips (Winbond brand) down to 10mhz.  But you must disable the DLL (there's a mode register bit for it).  Not guaranteed, but it works in practice and at such slow speeds you can get away with a whole lot of nonsense.